# Timer doesn't stop firing | Swift 5

Tags: swift, timer, nstimer, swift5

I have a timer initialized with `scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval interval: TimeInterval, repeats: Bool, block: @escaping (Timer) -> Void) -> Timer`. I'm trying to `invalidate()` it and set it to `nil` when I'm done with the escaping block execution. But even after invalidating it doesn't stop firing. I don't understand what's happening. Here is what I'm doing:

```
func startRecording() {
        do {
             ...
             guard recordTimer == nil else { return }
             recordTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.001, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                 progress += Float(self.recordTimer!.timeInterval)
                 ...
                 if progress >= 30 {
                    self.stopRecording()
                }
            }) }

func stopRecording() {
    recorder.stop()
        if recordTimer != nil {
            recordTimer?.invalidate()
            recordTimer = nil
        } }
```

This recordTimer object is set to invalidate and nil. But still the block keeps going. Please help.

**UPDATE:** The question has been solved. It was caused by reinitialization by a gesture recognizer just after the timer stopped firing. As I forcefully failed the gesture recognized, it's working fine.

*N.B.: I don't know how to close own question. If anyone can help, please let me know.*

Comment: Confirm that you’re actually calling `stopRecording`. For example, if you’re trying to call it from `deinit`, it will not get there, because you have a strong reference to `self` in your closure. We generally use `[weak self]` pattern if the closure to avoid those sorts of problems.

Comment: By the way, in `stopRecording`, the `if recordTimer != nil { ... }` is redundant because `recordTimer?.invalidate()` already does that (i.e. it only calls `invalidate` if `recordTimer` is not `nil`).

Comment: @Rob About redundancy, I didn't write the checking at first. But as I muddled through this site, many people advised that earlier. So, I tried it. And `stopRecording` is being called within a pan gesture handling function. I'm really unsure why the Timer instance isn't destroying. I'll try `weak self`.
Thanks!!

Comment: It's still there! 

Comment: @Rob I found the bug. It was not the Timer. It's a longPress gesture that was reinitializing the Timer. I needed to force fail the gesture.

Comment: @KoushikMudi  your code is not enter in if recordTimer != nil {} right?

Comment: @SagarBhut It's been solved. The timer never was the issue. It was another gesture recognizer that was reinitializing the timer.